# How to Update JSON data in an array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, laravel-5.8

I have a JSON Column in my table that has an array of JSON Data like this:

```
save_data
[
  {"option_id": 20000, "question_id": 10000}, 
  {"option_id": 20001, "question_id": 10001}, 
  {"option_id": 20002, "question_id": 10002}
]
```

I can get the record using this:

```
$save_data = DB::table('save_state')
    ->whereJsonContains('save_data', [["option_id" => 20002]])
    ->get();
```

But now what I want is to update only the option_id value of the element which has the question_id that I want, for example:

change option_id value to "20003" of question_id = "10002"

I have tried this but it still doesn't work.

```
$save_data = DB::table('save_state')
    ->whereJsonContains('save_data', [["option_id" => 20002]])
    ->update(['save_data->option_id' => [20003]]);
```

Comment: its possible, but i *strongly* suggest modelling your questions & options in a separate table.

Comment: @Haleemur Ali I have a model for both the question and option but I only need to save the id data in my DB